# Auth Guard canActivate not working for some reason

Tags: angular, guard, canactivate

When I add AuthGuard service with `canActivate` on routes, the app crashes when I try to go to  `/profile` and it redirect me to `localhost:4200`, not even `/home` and gives this error:

> ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

[image]

My code :

*app.routing.ts*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, CanActivate } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';

import { AuthGuardService as AuthGuard } from './auth-guard.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'', redirectTo:'/home', pathMatch:'full'},
 {path:'home',component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'login',component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'profile',component: ProfileComponent,canActivate: [AuthGuard]}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [AuthGuard],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

*app.module.ts*

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './profile/profile.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';

import { AuthGuardService as AuthGuard} from './auth-guard.service';
import { AuthService} from './auth.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ProfileComponent,
    TopbarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [AuthGuard, AuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*auth-guard.servce.ts*

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) { }

  canActivate():boolean{
          if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
              // logged in so return true
              return true;
          }

          // not logged in so redirect to login page
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
      }
}
```

It doesn't work!

Comment: Try to wrap the false part in the canActivate in an else block.

Comment: Is it definitely being caused by the AuthGuardService? If you comment out everything in canActivate, and simply return true, does it still error?

Comment: @user184994 tried to comment everything and return true; but i still get the same Error in my console, thanks for trying to help

Comment: Okay, so the issue seemingly isnt caused by that bit of code... And if you remove `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` from the route config, do you still get the error?

Comment: @user184994 when i remove canActivate: [AuthGuard] from the route config, everything works fine without any error

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your error when I copy that code I'm afraid: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tixhbd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fauth-guard.service.ts Can you fork that StackBlitz, and try to reproduce the error you're seeing?

Comment: @user184994 im not able to reproduce error with stackbltiz, code works fine with stackblitz.

Answer (score 8):

Had this same issue, solution was to add the Auth Guard to my providers in my app.module.ts

You should also make sure that this is the **only** file in which it is added to the providers.

```
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      // whatever your declarations are
  ],
  imports: [
      // Whatever your imports are
  ],
  providers: [
      AuthGuardService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: have u got any solution, please share

Comment: @Santhosh to my answer above, I added the AuthGuardService check the `providers` array of the module

Comment: I have more than one provider including authInterceptor.  What is the solution for multiple providers beside authGuard

Comment: @GoldenLion You can add as many classes annotated with @Injectable() as you like to the providers array of a module, but you must make sure that each class is only included in ONE providers array per app

Comment: if authguard is injectable why do I need to add it to the application provider array?

Comment: @GoldenLion prior to Angular 6 you had to add an `@Injectable()` service to the providers array, in Angular 6 and above if you use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` then you don't as this is basically declaring the same thing (root is an alias for AppModule in this case). All Injectable Services needed to be provided somewhere

Comment: thanks, that answers why there are differences in some of the tutorials about authguard

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work for me in app.module.ts. It has to be in app-routing.module.ts

In fact, it has to be in providers, in EVERY routing module that you want to use it in. ALSO, make sure to add ,canActivate:[AuthGuardName] to EACH line of the routes array, in every routing module you want to protect....